# Working on programming a retro z80 computer (SDCC error)

Tags: z80, assembly, c, sdcc

I am working on coding a driver of sorts for a Z80 based computer I am making. I am compiling with SDCC and I have been getting the following?

ASlink-Warning-Undefined Global 'data' referenced by module 'main'

I am essentially trying to access a c variable (function parameter) through inline assembly without messing with the stack (I would prefer solutions that don't involve the stack, but if that is the only way I would greatly appreciate you explaining how to do this and how it works with as much detail as possible and do an example for me). I am currently trying to use something like this:
ld A, (varname)
and it is throwing the error above.

I appreciate your help in advance :)

Edit:
A bit more info: I am compiling for the Z80 Processor and I am using the SDCC compiler on MacOS. The command I am using is: sdcc -mz80 --no-std-crt0 --vc --code-loc 0x0 src/main.c

And here is the code that is causing the error. It is in a file called pio.c and is connected to pio.h which I have attached to my main code by an include statement.

Pio.c:

```
#include "../../include/stdint.h"
#include "pio.h"

typedef struct pio
{
    uint8_t portA;
    uint8_t portB;
    void (*init)(char reg, uint8_t control);
    void (*load)(char reg, uint8_t data);
} PIO;
void init(char reg, uint8_t control){
    switch(reg){
        case 'A':
            __asm
                LD iy,#2
                ADD iy,sp
                LD A, 1(iy)
                OUT (0x13), A /*Output register a to the address 0000000000010011 */
            __endasm;
            break;
        case 'B':
            __asm
                OUT (0x9), A  /*Output register a to the address 000000000001001*/
            __endasm;
            break;
    }
}
void load(char reg, uint8_t data){
    switch(reg){
        case 'A':
             __asm
                mov A, data
                OUT (0x12), A /*Output register a to the address 0000000000010010*/
            __endasm;
            break;
        case 'B':
             __asm
                LD A, (IX)
                OUT (0x8), A /*Output register a to the address 0000000000010000*/
            __endasm;
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is Pio.h

```
/*
 * pio.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2020. 7. 28.
 *      Author: me
 *      LIB_PIO_PIO_H_
 */

#ifndef PIO_H
#define PIO_H
#include "pio.c"

extern void init(char reg, uint8_t control);
extern void load(char reg, uint8_t control);

#endif /* LIB_PIO_PIO_H_ */
```

An additional note, I know my first line of pio.c is for stdint in a higher folder. For some reason, the compiler won't see it if I just do a normal include, so I decided to copy all of the include files into my project directory. It is not great practice, but I just want it to work at this point.

Comment: I think this is easier to answer if you supply more information, like: exact code that is failing, what command line are you using and maybe what system are you compiling for.

Comment: Hello there, I updated the post to include my code and a bit more information. Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Which line is line 74? This: mov A, data? There is no 'mov' instruction on Z80.

Comment: Ok, so I went and switched it to LD A, (data) and it says, "Global 'data' referenced by module 'main'". I will update that in the post! I have been using a lot of different sources and just trying to see what works. I wasn't aware of that fact about the Z80. Anyways, the LD method is still not working and I updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the function parameter `data`, but the compiler does not expose that as a symbol to the internal assembler, so it's looking in the public, global namespace for it -- and can't find it.

According to [SDCC - Interfacing with Z80 assembler code](https://gist.github.com/Konamiman/af5645b9998c802753023cf1be8a2970), you do indeed need to access the parameters from the stack. I don't know if there are options to the compiler to not push the function parameter on to the stack.

> Parameters for the function are pushed to the stack before the
> function is called. They are pushed from right to left, so the
> leftmost parameter is the first one found when going up in the stack:

```
char SumTwoChars(char x, char y) __naked
{
    __asm
    ld iy,#2
    add iy,sp ;Bypass the return address of the function 

    ld l,(iy)   ;x
    ld a,1(iy)  ;y

    add l
    ld l,a      ;return value

    ret
    __endasm;
}
```